# How to send GET Request with JSON in Header in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to create an app which will locate an Scooters. I am using Bird(Scooter) api. I got an Auth token, but when I want to send request with GET method, with headers, it returns me response code `401`, but auth token is not null. Please help me. [Api Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afDcO.png)

*My request interface*

```
public interface ApiCallsInterface {

@Headers({
        "Device-id:43ba174c-11f4-4918-9fcc-6d785cfc256e"
        ,"Platform:android","Content-type:application/json"
})
@POST("/user/login")
Call<AuthResponseClass> getAuthToken(@Body Map<String, String> params);

@Headers({
        "Device-id:43ba174c-11f4-4918-9fcc-6d785cfc256e",
        "App-Version:3.0.5"
})
@GET("/bird/nearby?latitude=37.77184&longitude=-122.40910&radius=1000")
Call<BirdResponse> getBirds(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Header("Location") Map<String, String> params);}
```

*How I send request*

```
Map<String, String> requestParams = new HashMap<>();
requestParams.put("latitude",lat);
requestParams.put("longitude",lng);
requestParams.put("altitude","500");
requestParams.put("accuracy","100");
requestParams.put("speed","-1");
requestParams.put("heading","-1");

apiCallsInterface.getBirds(AUTH_TOKEN,requestParams).enqueue(new Callback<BirdResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<BirdResponse> call, Response<BirdResponse> response) {
        Log.d(TAG,"" + response.code());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BirdResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to append "Bird " before your token as in your api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

401 The request requires user authentication

Not adding the header properly here is the guide to generate header properly
 https://github.com/ubahnverleih/WoBike/blob/master/Bird.md